# google pagespeed ssl configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

Having trouble setting up pagespeed on my nginx server for https website.

On a normal http website, all images and resources are being cached by pagespeed, however when we switched the website to https, it says `Cannot fetch url xxx: as https is not supported` within the `pagespeed_global_admin/message_history` page however it says my domain is `Auth` in the `pagespeed_gloal_admin/conf` page.

I've added the following to pagespeed.conf file

```
pagespeed FetchHttps    enable,allow_self_signed;
```

and to the domain.conf file

```
pagespeed SslCertDirectory /etc/ssl/certs;
pagespeed SslCertFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt;
```

I've looked at https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/https_support#configuring_ssl_certificates and I have a few quesions, the SslCertFile says it should be a web server's HTTTPS client SSL key, not your domain SSL key, but whats the web server's HTTPS clinet SSL key?

Edit,
I'm running the web server in docker hosted on an AWS ec2 instance. Nginx is version 1.13.3 and pagespeed is 1.12.34.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Native fetcher for pagespeed is causing the problem.

Turn the nativefetcher off and see it solves your problem.

`pagespeed UseNativeFetcher off;`